# Parsing JSON Map to Another Map

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, hashmap

**OrderItem Model Class:**
This is my **OrderItem Model Class** which contains a CartItem Map as I am trying to Parse this I am getting error "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'"

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:practice_app/models/shippingAdress.dart';
import 'package:practice_app/providers/cart_provider.dart';

class OrderItem with ChangeNotifier {
final String? id;
final String? orderNo;
final DateTime? date;
final String? paymentMethod;
final ShippingAdress? shippingAdress;
final Map<String, CartItem>? cartItem;
final int? price;

OrderItem({
this.id,
this.orderNo,
this.date,
this.paymentMethod,
this.shippingAdress,
this.cartItem,
this.price,
});
factory OrderItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
print('Json:');
print(json);
//tempitems
final json1 = json['order'];
Map<String, CartItem> dd = {};
final temp =  CartItem.fromJson(json['order']) as Map<String, CartItem>;
final tempadd = ShippingAdress.fromJson(json['shippingAddress']) as ShippingAdress;
//final map = Map<String, CartItem>.from(temp);
print("printing temp items");
print(temp);
print("temp address");
//print(tempadd);
return OrderItem(
    id: json['ProductID'].toString(),
    orderNo: json['OrderNO'] ?? '',
    date: json['Date'] ?? DateTime.now(),
    paymentMethod: json['paymentMethod'] ?? 0,
    shippingAdress: tempadd,
    cartItem: temp,
    price: json["price"] ?? '');
}
```

**CartItem Model Class:**
Here is the fromJson Method Define for CartItem.

```
 import 'dart:async';
 import 'dart:convert';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

 class CartItem {
 String? id;
 String? plantId;
 String? title;
 num? price;
 int? quantity;
 String? imageAssets;
 String? size;
 Color? color;

 CartItem({
 this.id,
 this.plantId,
 this.title,
 this.price,
 this.quantity,
 this.imageAssets,
 this.size,
 this.color,
});

factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return CartItem(
  id: json['id'] as String,
  plantId: json['plantId'] as String,
  title: json['title'] as String,
  price: json['price'] as int,
  quantity: json['quantity'] as int,
  imageAssets: json['imageAsset'] as String,
  size: json['size'] as String,
  color: json['color'] ?? Colors.green[400] as Color,
 );
 }

 Map toJson() => {
    'id': this.id,
    'plantId': this.plantId,
    'title': this.title,
    'price': this.price,
    'quantity': this.quantity,
    'imageAsset': this.imageAssets,
    'size': this.size,
    'color': this.color,
  };
  }

  class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
 Map<String, CartItem> _item = {};

 Map<String, CartItem> get items {
return {..._item};
 }

 List<CartItem> get cartitem {
return [..._item.values.toList()];
 }

 int get itemCount {
return _item.length;
 }

 void emptyCart() {
_item.clear();
notifyListeners();
 }

 CartItem findById(String id) {
 return _item.values.toList().firstWhere((element) => element.id == id);
 }

 double get totalAmount {
double total = 0.0;
_item.forEach((key, cartItem) {
  total += cartItem.price! * cartItem.quantity!;
});

return total;
 }

 void removeItem(String productId) {
_item.remove(productId);
notifyListeners();
 }

 void updateCart(String id, CartItem newCart) {
// try {
if (_item.containsKey(id)) {
  _item.update(
    id,
    (value) => CartItem(
      plantId: newCart.plantId,
      id: newCart.id,
      title: newCart.title,
      price: newCart.price,
      quantity: newCart.quantity,
      imageAssets: newCart.imageAssets,
      size: newCart.size,
      color: newCart.color,
    ),
  );
}
notifyListeners();
//   final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
//   final cartData = json.encode(
//     {
//       _item,
//     },
//   );
//   prefs.setString('CartData', cartData);
// } catch (error) {
//   throw error;
// }
 }

 Future<void> addItem(String plantId, String quantity, String title,
  double price, String image, String size, Color color) async {
int quantityy = quantity == '' ? 1 : int.parse(quantity);

String sizee = size == 'Small'
    ? 'Small'
    : size == 'Large'
        ? 'Large'
        : size == 'Extra Large'
            ? 'Extra Large'
            : '';
try {
  if (_item.containsKey(plantId)) {
    //change Quantity
    _item.update(
      plantId,
      (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
        plantId: plantId,
        id: existingCartItem.id,
        title: existingCartItem.title,
        price: existingCartItem.price,
        imageAssets: existingCartItem.imageAssets,
        quantity: existingCartItem.quantity! + quantityy,
        size: sizee,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  } else {
    _item.putIfAbsent(
      plantId,
      () => CartItem(
        plantId: plantId,
        id: DateTime.now().toString(),
        title: title,
        price: price,
        imageAssets: image,
        quantity: quantityy,
        size: sizee,
        color: color,
      ),
    );
  }
  print(plantId);
  notifyListeners();

  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  //print(${cartitem.first.});
  final cartData = jsonEncode(
    {
      'cartItem': _item.toString(),
    },
  );
  prefs.setString('CartData', cartData);
  print(cartData);
  print('Shared done');
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
}
  }

  Future<bool> tryAutoFillCart() async {
final perfs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (!perfs.containsKey('CartData')) {
  return false;
}
final fetchCartData = perfs.getString('CartData');
final extractedCartData =
    jsonDecode(fetchCartData!) as Map<String, dynamic>;
_item = extractedCartData['cartItem'] as Map<String, CartItem>;
notifyListeners();
return true;
 }
  }
```

**API DATA RESPONSE:**
This is my Api data response I'm trying to parse specifically the order.

```
{
"StatusCode": 200,
"StatusMessage": "success",
"ProductID": 20,
"orderNO": 20,
"Date": null,
"paymentMethod": "Visa",
"shippingAddress": {
    "ID": "20",
    "FullName": "Ali",
    "ShippingAddress": "Stadium Road"
 },
 "order": [
    {
        "id": "p8",
        "plantId": "3",
        "title": "Ali",
        "imageAsset": "assets/images/plant3.png",
        "price": 80,
        "size": "Small",
        "color": null,
        "quantity": 4
    },
    {
        "id": "p8",
        "plantId": "3",
        "title": "IQBAL",
        "imageAsset": "assets/images/plant2.png",
        "price": 80,
        "size": "Small",
        "color": null,
        "quantity": 4
    }
],
"price": 1500,
"Message": null
}
```

**Error**
[Error I am getting trying to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iej5u.png)

Comment: In your api, "order" is of type List<CartItem>, not Map<String, CartItem>

Comment: How to convert it to Map<String, CartItem>?

Comment: Then you'll have to change the api response to Map<String, CartItem> from the backend.

Comment: Okay. thanks for clarification but if there is any other way that would be great.

Comment: You can change in your OrderItem model, from Map<String, CartItem> to List<CartItem> and change fromJson method. My point is: you should check the api response and define your model with the same type

Comment: I'd suggest you check this [guide](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) to know how each type of api response should be converted. You also can use this [website](https://app.quicktype.io) for easier api parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your coordination I resolved the issue for same API response using these two lines:
      `final temp = json['order'].map((e) => CartItem.fromJson(e));
       Map<String, CartItem>? bb = {for (var value in temp) value.id: value};`